# Grails throws Table "xxx" not found

Tags: hibernate, grails, h2

In Grails I can create domain objects to a H2 in memory dataSource in **BootStrap** and get results back ok, but once the app is up (eg query from GSP or controller) and I try to run a query I get this:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "FUNCTIONAL_DOC_TYPE" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.version as version1_0_, this_.direction_id as direction3_1_0_, this_.functional_group_id as functional4_1_0_, this_.type_name as type5_1_0_ from functional_doc_type this_ [42102-147]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
 at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
 at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4562)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1020)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1622)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1729)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1616)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1461)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1449)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:401)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:275)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:247)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.prepare(Parser.java:201)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:214)
 at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:425)
 at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:374)
 at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1056)
 at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
 at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:233)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
 at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findAll(GormStaticApi.groovy:374)
```

- I have cleaned the build
- Running Grails 2.0.0
- I had multiple datasources to SQL servers DB's that only do calls to 
  StoredProcedures and had now found a use case to use a H2 in memory store using good old Domain objects...the error only occurs on the
  domains.
- I ran the dbconsole and the only tables found are the standard 28
  "internal" tables...none are from my application

Some source:

Datasource.groovy

```
// "Parent" datasource def

dataSource_messages {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "user"
    password = "secret"
    readOnly = "true"
}


// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:app_data;MVCC=TRUE"
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
            readOnly = false
        }
        dataSource_messages {
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Messages"
        }
```

Domain class:

```
class FunctionalDocType {
    String typeName
    FunctionalGroup functionalGroup
    DocDirection direction

    static constraints = {
        functionalGroup(nullable: true)
    }

}
```

Bootstrap.groovy:

```
   new FunctionalDocType(typeName: 'Order',   direction: buyerToSeller, functionalGroup: orders).save().save(flush: true)

   //  insert into functional_doc_type (id, version, direction_id, functional_group_id, type_name) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)


   FunctionalDocType.findAll() runs:

    // DEBUG SQL - select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.version as version1_0_, this_.direction_id as direction3_1_0_, this_.functional_group_id as functional4_1_0_, this_.type_name as     type5_1_0_ from functional_doc_type this_
```

and all correct values are returned.

So its like the in memory tabes are being dropped after bootstrap somewhere but this is not being logged.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Does it work if you use a persisted database (database URL `jdbc:h2:~/test/app_data;MVCC=TRUE`)?

Comment: +1 to you Thomas, thanks for your answer; that does seem to work.  I'm still not sure why it didn't work the first way, I have not yet heard from the Grails group, but I think a persisted datastore should be ok for my use case.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

H2 closes the database when the last connection is closed. For an in-memory database, closing the connection means the data is lost...

So if you keep one connection open all the time, then you should be fine. You could call this a 'sentinel' connection.

Another option is to use a persistent database (database URL `jdbc:h2:~/test/app_data;MVCC=TRUE`)

Answer (score 2):

most inmemory database tie the database to the connection used. Hibernate opens a connection for each session so only the session with the SchemaExport has the database with the correct schema and is disposed immediatly. to solve this you have to use the same connection for all sessions which access the inmemory database.

```
connection = session.getConnection();

sessionfactory.openSession(connection);
```

Comment: Thanks Firo, a lesson learned.  I had made the assumption that because Grails by default for development mode was using the in memory it was ok, so had some faith this would not occur.  So I guess if I didnt run DB operations on Bootstrap then I would not see this issue.  Anyway thanks to you and Thomas I have 2 good options to explore and learned a little more about in memory DB's.  Cheers!