# Grails H2 Database will not initialize

Tags: grails, groovy, h2

I've been spending the last couple of days just trying to get a barebones version of a Grails project to run. After moving through various problems dealing with Java version incompatibilities and buggy IDEs I can see the home stretch! But this last problem has me vexed.

My grails 2.4.4 project is using H2 and I'm running the application in Dev mode. I get a bunch of error messages like this:

> Error | 2015-09-27 00:22:16,096 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "ORDER_DELIVERY" not found; SQL
>   statement: alter table order_delivery drop constraint
>   FK_syi9a9vft4d15lq78cx3e1m38 if exists [42102-176]

I thought maybe these errors were related to this:
[Grails 2.4 and hibernate4 errors with run-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858953/grails-2-4-and-hibernate4-errors-with-run-app)
and that I could just ignore them. But when I got the dbconsole of my app it show no tables whatsoever. With that being said it seemed to be the problem described in this question:

[Grails throws Table "xxx" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907303/grails-throws-table-xxx-not-found)

But I tried the accepted solution of using disk space and that has not solved the problem. Any ideas? I'm using Spring Security and Spring security with rest though disabling it hasn't helped.

from my **Datasource.groovy**:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:C:/temp/app_data;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
}
```

My bootstrap class. SecUser and SecRole were generated by the s2 quickstart script, and my User domain extends SecUser. The User.findAll() command **returns an empty list**:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        User user = new User(username: "test", password: "test123", 
            email: "test@guy.com", name: "Dakota Roberts", title: "MD", active: true)
        user.save()

        SecRole roleUser = new SecRole(authority: "ROLE_USER")
        roleUser.save()

        new SecUserSecRole(user: user, role: roleUser).save()

        def users = User.findAll()
        for(User chkUser : users) {
            println chkUser.name
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

User domain class example. It extends SecUser which sets tablePerHierarchy to false:

```
@Resource(uri="/user")
class User extends SecUser {
    String email
    String name
    String title
    Boolean active
    static belongsTo = [organization : Organization]
    static constraints = {
        email email: true, unique: true, blank: false
        name blank: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your database file being created? If not try this for the connection: jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/app_data;MVCC=TRUE

Comment: Hey Emmanuel- it is being created. Three files are in my temp dir

Comment: Does it work with an in-memory H2 db?

Comment: I don't follow you... I am using an in-memory H2 db as you can see in the datasource config.

Comment: Your datasource.groovy shows a file-based H2 db. An in-memory connection would look like this: jdbc:h2:mem:app_data

Comment: Ah, I understand. Yes, I started with an in-memory and switched to file based to see if that would fix the problem. Neither worked

Comment: If you don't have any tables your domain.save()s should fail. Try doing your save()s in BootStrap.groovy like this: `domain.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` I'm expecting an error that would provide a clue.

Comment: I just realized something. When you checked the H2 database with the dbconsole, did the JDBC URL match the one in DataSource.groovy?

Comment: I have this working now... unfortunately I'm not sure precisely what the source problem was so I just switched to mySql. I found the failOnError flag helpful and I was not aware of its existence. If you would like to add this comment as an answer I will accept it.